# Hard resetting link, limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps from non-existent disk

Tags: debian, performance, hard-drive, sata

Good morning!

Can anyone help me with a strange problem that I have in my Debian 8.8 Jessie server? I'm having these messages in my syslog:

[lun may 24 10:23:09 2021] ata9: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps 
[lun may 24 10:23:09 2021] ata9: hard resetting link
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: EH complete
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[lun may 24 10:23:12 2021] ata9: hard resetting link
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: EH complete
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[lun may 24 10:23:14 2021] ata9: hard resetting link
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: EH complete
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[lun may 24 10:23:17 2021] ata9: hard resetting link
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: EH complete
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[lun may 24 10:23:19 2021] ata9: hard resetting link

And it goes on and on and on. Disk problem, not a big deal I thought.
Okay, so I executed this command in order to see my SATA devices, so I can discover which disk is this "ata9" device and come with a solution.

`find -L /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/ata*/host*/target* -maxdepth 3 -name "sd*" 2>/dev/null | egrep block |egrep --colour '(ata[0-9]*)|(sd.*)'`

And I got:

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:11.4/**ata1**/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:11.4/**ata2**/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:11.4/**ata3**/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:11.4/**ata4**/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sdd
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/**ata5**/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sde
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/**ata6**/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdf
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/**ata7**/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdg
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/**ata8**/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdh
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:81:00.0/**ata11**/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdi
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:81:00.0/**ata12**/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdj

So, just discovered that I have no **ata9** device.

Can anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Comment: are u sure that you don't own a physical drive That may be broken? or connected a broken but not used cable?

Comment: I went to my rack and checked the disks like a kid, counting them with my fingers and checking serial numbers, but everything went good... Although I didn't check the sata cables, are you saying that one may be connected to the motherboard without a disc and this cable is giving this errors? I will check it later, Thank you for the advice!

Comment: additional, you should check all drives and connectors, in case ata9 is misdiagnosed and a other drive makes a fluke to you, however the message mostly comes from bad cable(s)